How to make .OwnsOne() objects not null by default?
So I've inherited an app that I've recently upgraded from .NET Core 2 to .NET 8. It uses entityframework and a lot of .OwnsOne().
After updating I ran into the problem that, in the previous version of EF (2.2.6) whenever I select anything that uses those I get an instance of a class with everything set to default. This has changed and it will only create an instance of a class if I tell it to, or I create that class if it's null. As in I'd have to find all places that uses that navigation property and do
protected void UpdateSelf(Tour tour) 
{
  // Has a lot of property updates that I've ommitted
  // It also calls .UpdateSelf() on other owned types. In this case they would have already be created with values, and won't be null on select

  if (Completion == null)
    Completion = new Completion(null, null);

  Completion.UpdateSelf(tour.Completion);
}

To avoid exceptions. The class itself is this:
    [Owned]
    public class Completion : IEquatable<Completion>
    {
#nullable enable
        public DateTime? CompletedTime { get; private set; }
        public string? Comment { get; private set; }
        //private Completion() { }

        public Completion(DateTime? completedTime, string? comment)
        {
            CompletedTime = completedTime;
            Comment = comment;
        }
#nullable disable

        internal void UpdateSelf(Completion completion)
        {
            if (completion == null) return;
            CompletedTime = completion.CompletedTime;
            Comment = completion.Comment;
        }
        
        // And the IEquatable implementation
    }

And is configured on the entity like so:
builder.OwnsOne(t => t.Completion);

And selecting it
var target = await _dbContext.PlantToDepotTours
  .Where(t => t.Id == dto.Id)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Not really anything groundbreaking. But I'd really like to know if there was a way to configure EF to make Completion not be null on select. It's not marked as nullable either.
I also know I can do
builder.OwnsOne(t => t.Completion);
builder.Navigation(t => t.Completion).IsRequired().AutoInclude();

But that would require me to add it on all the navigation properties, and it doesn't seem like it would produce the same behaviour either.

Can you share one of the model using Completion  as a property?

The full model? It has a lot of properties, but Completion is declared like this: public Completion Completion { get; private set; }. It's from a Tour object, and Completion is expected to be updated under a protected void UpdateSelf(Tour tour)

You could make it a struct. This would also simplify the two UpdateSelf methods or even make them obsolete.

Okay so looking more into it I think what I needed was ComplexProperty. At least from this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef8-rc1/#configuration-of-complex-types4
I'm gonna have to test this (and edit this reply). But if I do
builder.ComplexProperty(t => t.Completion).IsRequired();

in the configuration I seem to get the same behaviour as the previous version

I just found an excellent answer to What is difference between ComplexType and OwnsOne in Entity Framework Core?.

Yeah that is an excellent answer (that I wish I had gotten while researching) and seems to confirm that ComplexProperty is what I needed all the time. I regex replaced all OwnsOne to the above, and so far it seems to work as intended

You can accept your own answer to close the question.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Oh I know. And I plan on doing it when it gets out into production
